# magento 500 error in checkout/onepage. PHP-Error with: /lib/Zend/Validate.php

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I don't know what to do right now. I really hope to find some help here.

I just uploaded my local magento store (1.9.2.1) to a hoster. Everything looks fine and works, except one thing: When I want to checkout, it redirects me to the checkout/onepage and returns a white page.

- Firebug - Networktab tells me it's a `500 internal Server Error`.
- `php_error_log: [error] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Validate_Hostname' not found in /www/dev/lib/Zend/Validate.php on line 228`

I already fixed file (644) and folder (755) Permissions on the server.
I also changed theme back to basic. Memory-Limit at 512MB. On my local machine running an xampp there is no problem.

I have a prior instance running on the hoster with magento 1.9.0.1. There is no problem with issue.

Does anyone have an idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was, like always, missing files on the server. The FTP programm did no upload every file. My bad.

The best way to upload magento to your hoster: zip the magento folder, upload to hoster and unzip (if possible).